# Local version of jquery not working right

Tags: jquery

Developing a theme for someone else, nornally on sites I'd maintain I'd use google CDN to load jquery like so:

```
//don't use (deregister) WP's jQuery version
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

//Use jQuery from Google Code
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery'););
```

But after deleting that WordPress's local version breaks my site, it's loading the same version just from wp-includes, jquery 1.11.1.

When I use google CDN it's all fine.

When I use the local version it just throws up errors in my JS like 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' on the first line of my main.js file.

Totally perplexed as to what would cause this issue.

Comment: When you removed the deregistering of the Google CDN version, did you enqueue jquery or did you delete that line too?

Comment: It loads the enqueued version either way. I can see it's loading from wp-includes. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.1.141:8888/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1"></script>`